# Java Keystore.getKey() slow while Key store size Increase

Tags: java, encryption, keystore, java-security

I am using java key store to store and retrieve encryption key.It works faster while my key store size is small. But once my key store size is increased than key store operation goes slow.

I am working on linux platform, Java version Jdk_1.8. and safenet as provider.

Comment: What is the size of the store when performance becomes a problem? Please add this information to the question, not as an answer.

Comment: Is this related to the question by @Nirav Shah? If so please coordinate and delete one of the questions.  Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/38456568/451475

Comment: Ok,It seems like that. but my question is regards to keystore limitation. Thanks Zaph

Comment: Interesting, both of you seem to work for the same company and ask essentially the same question 30 minutes apart. Suggestion: coordinate and work together on the problem.

Comment: yes Mr.Zaph , will coordinate and work together on problem

Answer (score 3):

I have been facing the same issue related to execution speed varies with different operation system platform.

Jvm loads key store in memory. And its having hashtable collection as internal storage.

Hashtable is synchronized.

Whenever you perform get operation from key store, than it will return it from in-memory key store not from physical keystore.
You can confirm it by using ("top" - %wa section) command in linux base OS.

Key store is using hashtable and it is the root cause behind performance decriment.

I have solved this issue by loading all keys from keystore into ConcurrentHashMap while initializing the project. and later on,
All the read operation will be performed from MAP instead of keystore.
And make sure that all write operation will be perform on both keystore and MAP.

Comment: yes its work for me. i used map to read data and it works for me .. but why java keystore use hastable ?

Answer (score 2):

We have faced this issue when we were using safenet jar file as a key store provider, when I removed safenet as a provider & used default providers of java then I didn't face any performance related issue.