# Java keystore slows encryption / decryption down

Tags: java, performance, encryption

I am building a little program for encryption and decryption of some personal data, in order to learn more about encryption. The program uses RSA and AES encryption, depending on the content size that needs to be encrypted.

In a first, draft implementation, I stored the keys just to a text file, and read them from there. The different tests that I ran were quite fast. In general, encrypting small to large strings, took not more than 30ms, and in general 15ms.

I then moved the keys to a java Keystore and read them from there. This slowed the encryption down drastically. A test function that used to take about 15ms went to 1 to 2 seconds, sometimes even nearing 3 seconds, depending on the content that needed to be tokenized.

From here [Java Keystore.getKey() slow while Key store size Increase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457864/java-keystore-getkey-slow-while-key-store-size-increase/38459647#38459647) I learned that storing the keys in a ConcurrentHashMap should increase the speed of the encryption/decryption. I tried this and now indeed, the encryption/decryption, became faster, taking about 800 to 900ms. This is certainly an improvement compared to the 1/2 seconds I was experiencing with reading the keys each time from the keystore, but it is still not as fast as the 16ms that the original method took, in which the keys were just read from a text file.

This leaves me with two questions:

- Are there other 'tricks' I should explore, that could make the encryption process faster. Ideally, the encryption/decryption time would be marginal, so when I want to use this e.g. to encrypt my database, there would not be a drastic performance issue.
- Does storing the keys in a ConcurrentHashMap come with other disadvantages (let's say security wise) that I need to be aware of?

I am using the java keystore.

Comment: Are you encrypting the database as a file or on a per-record basis? If You do it an a per-record basis then always using the same key (e.g. from a keystore) is a bad idea. A good crypto scheme derives an own key for every database record. Use one master key and derive all the other keys from that master key.

Comment: It would indeed be the idea to encrypt on a per-record basis, but the current function is just a general String encrypt(input) function. Encrypting the database is the long-term goal. For now I am just experimenting with different setups, trying to create an efficient encryption method.